# Client side data binding with knockout js and MVC action method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

i am new in mvc. so i am not sure that when page is requested first time then a action method is called. if we deliver the json from that action method then how could we hold that json from client side and parse that json by knockout and bind controls.

i came across few article on asp.net mvc and knockout but those all bind control at server side at the first request and from the subsequent action they call server side/ action method function by jquery and what json that action method return they just parse and populate knockout with those json.

so is it possible to capture json when page requested first time and populate knockout view model.
help with sample code would be very helpful for me.

do we need to use any other knockoutjs for mapping json and bind data? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller would populate a model which is bound to the ASP.net view. Then in the view you would use need to serialize the c# model to json. Here I'm using json.net. Then you can bind it to the html on the view.

So If your C# Model is this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And then your controller is this:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    // GET: Person
    public ActionResult Edit(int personId)
    {
        //this is where you would load the person from your data source
        var person = _datasource.GetPerson(personId);

        return View(person);
    }
}
```

Then in your view you would serialise to json within a script tag:

```
$(function() {
    var personModel = '@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)';
    ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel(personModel));
});
```

You would put all your view models in javascript files that are bundled up and minified using asp.net bundling.

This would be `PersonViewModel.js`:

```
var PersonViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable(model.FirstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(model.LastName);

    self.save = function () {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: please give me mvc action method too who will send json to client. thanks

Comment: The action doesn't send json to the client. It sends a view to the client that contains a variable that is assigned the json. Above it's called personModel

Comment: Does that make sense? This is how MVC works. The action would return a view with the model bound to it. Then in the view the model would be serialised to json and then bound to the html using knockout.

Comment: it would be better if you provide full code with server side action method. thanks

Comment: Ok, but it has nothing to do with Knockout. It seems you are having trouble grasping the concept of MVC. Knockout is implemented in the view, hence there is nothing knockout related in the controller.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the c# code. As you can see it didn't really add anything that was really relevant to the question

Comment: yes i have seen. thanks. just like to understand this code `var personModel = '@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)';` here can we give any name say for MyModel instead of Model?

Comment: Model is what is used for mvc Model. In ASP.net mvc in your view to access the model bound to the view you use the Model property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68495/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-mou).