# Knockout date validation ob

Tags: validation, knockout.js

My question is in reference to an older question on Stack Overflow:

[Knockout validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996449/knockout-validation)

The question is regarding date validation in knockout.js and knockout.validation.js.

Does anyone have a good example of knockout binding in MVC 4 that validates a date entry?

Using the above link I implemented the following sample:

```
ko.validation.rules['simpleDate'] = {
        validator: function (val, validate) {
            return ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(val) || moment(val, 'MM/DD/YYYY').isValid();
        },
        message: 'Invalid date'
    };
```

next, I bound the rules:

```
self.ChildDateOfBirth = ko.observable().extend({ simpleDate: true });
```

The whole idea behind this is if the user enters 14/02/2009 then loses focus then a message should popup next to the box as invalid date.

I must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you call `ko.validation.registerExtenders();` after you added the validation rule?

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation#user-content-custom-validation-rules) you need to call it.

It's working in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pry38zh/1/).

Comment: I did..I was also using MVC 4.0 model..would that be another issue? I noticed that you added the data-binding I'm guessing that is something i need to add?

Comment: Yep. That's how knockout works. You need to bind each field to your client side viewModel. You would normally convert the MVC model to json and assign it to a variable and then pass that into your viewmodel constructor which would then populate your observables. Take a look at one of my [previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27862522/2326610) that shows how to do it

Comment: I'm going to give this a try - this is most helpful.